# Need help solving this basic algebra question (addition and division)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Believe it or not I graduated with a BSc in Computing Science, but apparently that means nothing after being out of school for a year.

The question is:

> $\frac{(c+n)}{(t+n)}=\frac{1}{4}$

Solve for $n$.

My attempt:

> $c+n=\frac{1}{4}(t+n)$
>   $c+n= \frac{1}{4}t+\frac{1}{4}n$
>   $c+\frac{3}{4}n=\frac{1}{4}t$
>   $\frac{3}{4}n=\frac{1}{4}t-c$
>   $n=\frac{4}{3}(\frac{1}{4}-c)$

But when I plug in the numbers I have, that doesn't work out, so there must be a mistake in there somewhere, but I can't seem to spot it.

Help?

---

The numbers I've got are:

$t=3035$
$c=413$

And the answer I expect for $n$ is $461$.

Comment: In going to the last line, the $t$ disappeared! You want $n=(4/3)(0.25t-c)$.

Comment: You assumed the worst about your math skills too soon. The more one writes, the more misteaks there will be.

Comment: @user6312: Haha... but I like me steaks! I think I always always this bad, overlooking such basic mistakes. Once I screwed up the math so bad that the answer I got in the end was actually correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you just forgot the $t$ in your last step. Should be $n=\frac{4}{3}(\frac{1}{4}t-c)$.

Comment: Oops. That was just me forgetting to type it though....that's not the only mistake, is it? **Edit:** Nevermind. That was the mistake. I'm an idiot :D Math works out now.

Comment: @Mark: you're not an idiot :)  We've all been there, done that...

Answer (score 4):

In the last line, $t$ has disappeared.